# Netbeans import takes wrong source file

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I have the source code of a "util" maven project multiple times on my PC. In one directory I added a function to a class and called `mvn clean install` to make the new `jar` available in other projects.

In my main project I include the "util" dependency and can see in the NetBeans `Project-tree->Dependencies`, that the included jar file contains my changes. However, NetBeans throws an compile error that the new function cannot be found. If I open the imported file (Crtl+click import link), NetBeans opens a source file of a wrong (old) directory.

How do I fix this behavior?

**Edit**: I deleted the NetBeans Cache without success...

**Edit2**: I pulled the current version into the "old" directory and NetBeans compiles. Somehow the "jar" is ignored and for-what-reason this directory seams to be the reference...

Comment: I am no Netbeans expert, but I guess you did not add the dependency as Maven dependency (i.e. in the `pom.xml` as `<dependency>`).

Comment: I did. Thats why I showed up in the dependecy tree.

Comment: Maybe you have something similar to Eclipse workspace resolution which automagically replaces a jar by an open project. In Eclipse, this can be configured.